# Ordering entries via comment count with django

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-comments

I need to get entries from database with counts of comments. Can i do it with django's comment framework? I am also using a voting application which is not using GenericForeignKeys i get entries with scores like this:

```
class EntryManager(models.ModelManager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(EntryManager,self).get_queryset(self).all().annotate(\
            score=Sum("linkvote__value"))
```

But when there is foreignkeys i am being stuck. Do you have any ideas about that?

extra explaination: i need to fetch entries like this:

```
id | body | vote_score | comment_score |
 1 |  foo |         13 |             4 |
 2 |  bar |          4 |             1 |
```

after doing that, i can order them via comment_score. :)

Thans for all replies.

Comment: annotating with comment_count=Count('comment') doesn't work? .. (you better check what the db field of the comments are.. dont know django comments from memory..

Comment: Check out [this](https://github.com/coleifer/django-generic-aggregation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, annotating with reverse generic relations (or extra filters, in general) is still an [open ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10870) (see also the [corresponding documentation](https://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/10781)). Until this is resolved, I would suggest using raw SQL in an `extra` query, like this:

```
return super(EntryManager,self).get_queryset(self).all().annotate(\
    vote_score=Sum("linkvote__value")).extra(select={
        'comment_score': """SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments_comment
            WHERE comments_comment.object_pk = yourapp_entry.id
            AND comments_comment.content_type = %s"""
    }, select_params=(entry_type,))
```

Of course, you have to fill in the correct table names. Furthermore, `entry_type` is a "constant" that can be set outside your lookup function (see [ContentTypeManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#the-contenttypemanager)):

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
entry_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Entry)
```

This is assuming you have a single model `Entry` that you want to calculate your scores on. Otherwise, things would get slightly more complicated: you would need a sub-query to fetch the content type id for the type of each annotated object.